# alter characters in between two defined words

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, text, replace

**Background**

I have the following df

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Text' : ['But the here is SERG BATH # : S00-1111 MR # 111 is Here ', 
                                   'Found here SERG BATH # : E22-22222 MR # 000', 
                                   'So so SERG BATH # : L88-888 MR # 975 hey the ',
                                'The SERG BATH # : V99-99 MR # 232 here but',
                              'The is not here is the SERG BATH # : A33-3 MR # 212 here and'],


                      'ID': [1,2,3,4,5],
                       'P_ID': ['A','B','C','D','E'],

                     })
```

**Goals**

1) Block all characters in between `SERG BATH # :` and   `MR #`

2) Create new column `New_Text`

**Example**

Change

```
"SERG BATH # : A33-3 MR #"
```

into

```
"SERG BATH # : **BLOCK** MR #"
```

**Desired Output**

```
   ID P_ID  Text  New_Text
0                 "But the here is SERG BATH # : **BLOCK** MR # 111 is Here"
1                 "Found here SERG BATH # : **BLOCK**  MR # 000"
2                 "So so SERG BATH # : **BLOCK** MR # 975 hey the"
3                 "The SERG BATH # : **BLOCK**  MR # 232 here but"
4                 "The is not here is the SERG BATH # : **BLOCK**  MR # 212 here and"
```

Comment: What have you tried? Edit question to include your attempts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
df['New_Text'] = df['Text'].str.replace('BATH \# \:(.+?)MR \#','BATH #  :*** Block *** MR #')
```